# Multiplying floats and ints in perl through an if statement

Tags: perl, int, conditional-statements

My goal is to utilize perl to multiply a float and an int, I have got this far and am still researching, many thanks to any help.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$float1 = 0.90

print "give me an integer";
$that_integer = <>;
if ($that_integer<=5000) {
     print "$that_integer * $float1";
}
```

Comment: Add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` near the top.

Comment: missing `;` at `$float1 = 0.90`

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Perl.  A few tips:

- Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY Perl script.
- [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input from `<STDIN>` to remove the newline at the end.
- You can't interpolate expressions.  However, you can easily include them in a string easily using [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html).

As demonstrated:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $float1 = 0.90;

print "give me an integer: ";
chomp( my $that_integer = <> );

if ( $that_integer <= 5000 ) {
    printf "%f\n", $that_integer * $float1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary expressions can't be interpolated into double-quotes. Try:

```
print $that_integer * $float1, "\n";
```

The **perlop** documentation page includes all the [gory details of parsing quoted constructs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs).